# put listView child in a hashmap

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I'm trying to fetch values from listView with a for loop and put them in a hashmap. but the logcat keeps throwing this error. I can't figure out why. Any help please! the list view has @android:id/list and I have extended ListActivity on my activity here is my code to fetch those values

```
listStudent=getListView();
studentMarksList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
String student,obtained_value,max_value;
for (int i=0;i<listStudent.getCount();i++) {
    View view=listStudent.getChildAt(i);
    studentIdTxt=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_id_ls);
    obtainedTxt=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.obtained);
    maxTxt=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.max);
    student=studentIdTxt.getText().toString();
    obtained_value=obtainedTxt.getText().toString();
    max_value=maxTxt.getText().toString();
    //updating the new mark list array
    HashMap<String,String>studentMark=new HashMap<String,String>();
    studentMark.put(TAG_STUDENT_ID,student);
    studentMark.put(TAG_MARKS_OBTAINED,obtained_value);
    studentMark.put(TAG_MARKS_MAX,max_value);
    studentMarksList.add(studentMark);
}
```

And here is my xml layout for the list

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="106dp" />
```

and here is the xml for list items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/student_name_ls"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textColor="#1e5401"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- Marks label -->
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/obtained"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textColor="#acacac"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:numeric="decimal" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/max"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textColor="#0b0b0b"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:editable="false" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/student_id_ls"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textColor="#060606"
    android:visibility="gone" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

And the problem is on this line "studentIdTxt=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_id_ls);" throws nullpointerexception any help please

Comment: Can't you get it from the datasource directly? Can you post the code where you initialize the `ListView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
listStudent.getChildCount()
```

This is because the number of views in a list view is equal to the number of views you see. It is not equal to the number of items in the listview. So if you would use getCount() you would eventually get a indexOutOfBoundsException because there are no more views.